Throwing a ball in the air
When we throw a ball in the air, we know that if we do not throw it too high, then g can be held constant over the trajectory and we can approximate the curve by a parabola. However we also know that if we project a body at a height from the surface of the earth and the velocity is lower than the first cosmic velocity $v<(\frac {GM}{R})^{1/2}$ then the path followed by the body will be an ellipse. So then we can say that the trajectory is an ellipse. So in this case we approximated an ellipse by a parabola. Can we always do this?

If all of the satellites that have been launched into space followed parabolic trajectories instead of following elliptical trajectories, where would they be now?

Even at the fringes of space, gravity is still pretty strong. Eg, at 100 km the acceleration is ~96.9% of g at sea level. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkFFLwzAQx9%5FzKY4I0s6RZena6dhEhYEvgvTFl6HENkuDXbalt7IhfnevnT4sD4H7cfnd%5F8I5h6UOWIENunV4gmswTaF3BlpTbwsiDOi8BYdoPHye4PUFVO68BSXVRMhMjCeMc85YDgvIkmkqJuNMTZMkMwlc%5FXk1uq3XNQRdukPDLLXeiVuZZSm1NKh9qUP5n4GxB%2DfRBF0gK80aPiI84uIZN%5FXT9hjxeZXcX2Sej4jweEhJq0XEdY0OD6WB6GsT8yGMpYzjWb9GoLk53HRIwgCqHu4JRjmMIMQwGIDqoe0i7qnH9uUuUKJozR%2DLwtSUrFtn5UFT07e1M5Guf2Azat5VB%5Fbn2vK4f9t2ftWpLF3nIVKkF96VX17%2DOsm%5F25lQZy%2DZfgFC%5F3X5&lang=python


In this case we approximated an ellipse by a parabola. Can we always do this ?

Yes. The equation of an ellipse centred on the origin is
$\displaystyle \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$
If we move the origin to one end of the ellipse then we have
$\displaystyle \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {(y+b)^2}{b^2} = 1
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} + \frac {2y}{b}= 0$
Close to the origin (i.e. near one end of the ellipse) we have $y \ll b$ so we can ignore the $\frac {y^2}{b^2}$ term and we have
$\displaystyle \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {2y}{b} \approx 0
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow y \approx - \frac {b}{2a^2} x^2$
In other words near one end an ellipse can always be approximated by a parabola

+1.  Key to this is the $y \ll b$ of the answer, which says "y is sufficiently small compared to b."  The definition of sufficient depends on the particular experiment, and the constraints you have on the outcome.  Throwing a ball is a very low-precision activity, so its easy to say $y \ll b$
